# Set a property for a PowerShell class on Instantiation

Tags: class, powershell

Is it possible to have the value of a property of a PowerShell class defined on instantiation without using a constructor?

Let's say there's a cmdlet that will return Jon Snow's current status (alive or dead).  I want that cmdlet to assign that status to a property in my class.

I can do this using a constructor, but I'd like this to happen regardless of which constructor is used, or even indeed if one is used at all.

```
function Get-JonsCurrentStatus {
    return "Alive"
}

Class JonSnow {

    [string]
    $Knowledge

    [string]
    $Status

    #Constructor 1
    JonSnow()
    {
        $this.Knowledge = "Nothing"
        $this.Status = Get-JonsCurrentStatus
    }

    #Constructor 2
    JonSnow([int]$Season)
    {
        if ($Season -ge 6) 
        {
            $this.Knowledge = "Still nothing"
            $this.Status = Get-JonsCurrentStatus #I don't want to have to put this in every constructor
        }
    }

}

$js = [JonSnow]::new()
$js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, **you cannot call other constructors in the *same* class with `: this()`** (though you *can* call a *base class* constructor with `: base()`)<sup>[1]</sup>

Your best bet is a **workaround with a *(hidden) helper method***:

```
function Get-JonsCurrentStatus {
    return "Alive"
}

Class JonSnow {

    [string]
    $Knowledge

    [string]
    $Status

    # Hidden method that each constructor must call
    # for initialization.
    hidden Init() {
      $this.Status = Get-JonsCurrentStatus
    }

    #Constructor 1
    JonSnow()
    {
        # Call shared initialization method.
        $this.Init()
        $this.Knowledge = "Nothing"
    }

    #Constructor 2
    JonSnow([int]$Season)
    {
        # Call shared initialization method.
        $this.Init()
        if ($Season -ge 6) 
        {
            $this.Knowledge = "Still nothing"
        }
    }

}

$js = [JonSnow]::new()
$js
```

---

[1] The reason for this **by-design limitation**, as [provided by a member of the PowerShell team](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3820#issuecomment-302750422) is:

> We did not add : this() syntax because there is a reasonable alternative that is also somewhat more intuitive syntax wise

The linked comment then recommends the approach used in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialise class properties on instantiation this way:

```
$jon = new-object JonSnow -Property @{"Status" = Get-JonsCurrentStatus; "Knowledge" = "Nothing"}
```

Comment: BTW, it can be shortened to `[JonSnow] @{"Status" = Get-JonsCurrentStatus; "Knowledge" = "Nothing"}`.

Comment: Nice shorthand, was not aware of that. I'll leave the answer as is though as I prefer it to be verbose for people to better understand what is going on.