# PowerShell 5.1 What's the newer way of creating a PSCredential object

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

What's a newer way of creating the PSCredential object?

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList $_config.DBUserID, $_config.DBPassword
```

I was reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1#converting-a-hashtable) that this is the legacy way of creating the object. I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: What issue are you having? Is the existing method not working?

Comment: I was reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1#converting-a-hashtable)  that this is the legacy way of creating the object. I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @Rod That is specific to the PSCustomObject. Yeah, in that case I understand. The `[PSCustomObject]@{Prop1 = 'Value1';Prop2='Value2'}` is the preferred way when you compare it to `New-Object`. It is much more convenient to declare your PSCustomObject using a hashtable that you cast into a PSCustomObject. I don't see the older way stopping working anytime soon though.

Comment: What's the object difference between `ConvertFrom-Json` and `PSCustomObject`?

Comment: I dont understand your question, `ConvertFrom-Json` is a cmdlet and `PSCustomObject` is a type accelerator that allows you to create objects on the fly. There is no correlation between those 2

Answer (score 2):

The link from your last comment was regarding the `PSCustomObject` creation specifically.

The "Legacy" approach from Microsoft Doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1#converting-a-hashtable) was

```
$myHashtable = @{
    Name     = 'Kevin'
    Language = 'PowerShell'
    State    = 'Texas'
}

$myObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $myHashtable
```

It is still a valid way to do it and I don't see it going away anytime soon. That being said, you can cast a hashtable into a PSCustomObject directly instead, which is the preferred way. It is shorter and right to the point.

```
$myHashtable = @{
    Name     = 'Kevin'
    Language = 'PowerShell'
    State    = 'Texas'
}
$myObject = [pscustomobject]$myHashtable
```

---

**My original answer, that was regarding the PSCredential specifically**

The way you are creating your credentials is perfectly fine.

I personally use the `[PsCredential]::New($Username,$Password)` constructor but it is not a better alternative.

In fact, using the `New-Object` still have an advantage over using the constructor, which is that you can set properties that are not part of the constructor upon object creation, which you cannot do when using the constructor.

Here is how you create a PSCredential object using the constructor

```
# Name credentials
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = [PSCredential]::New($username,$password)
```

**VSCode snippet I created myself for reference**

(Trivia: I named my snipped "cheap-cred" because having credentials in plain text in a script is not the best practice and it is a permanent reminder of that each time I use it.)

```
    "cheap-cred": {
        "prefix": "cheap-cred",
        "body": [
            "# ${1:Name} credentials",
            "\\$username = '${2:Username}'",
            "\\$password = '${3:Password}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force",
            "\\$credential = [PSCredential]::New(\\$username,\\$password)\r\r$0"
        ],
        "description": "Create credentials object from string within script (insecure)"
    }
```

**Reference:**

You can read about object creation in the official doc, where both method are shown, with no indication of a legacy one: [about_Object_Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: You can use hashtable with the new syntax. There is literally no advantage of using `new-object` as far as I know

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `New-Object` only advantage is more of an edge case but it allow you to set properties that are not part of the constructor at the time the object is instancied. Most of the time, it doesn't matter. You create the object, then change relevant properties but at very rare occasion, I had objects where the properties needed to be set ahead of time when object was created or otherwise it wouldn't work properly. the tl;dr is : You cannot set `-Property` when using `[Class]::New()`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This question / answer is exactly what I mean [set-a-property-for-a-powershell-class-on-instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035003/set-a-property-for-a-powershell-class-on-instantiation)

Comment: Yes you can, actually an answer from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/a/72705298/15339544 as long as you target the right property names

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon If you need to use a different constructor than the empty one or an empty one do not exist, then you can't cast to an object from an hashtable. Not a very exciting example but : `[pscredential]::new('Username')` will work and `[pscredential]@{'Username'='Username'}`  won't since `PSCredential` do not have a 0 arg constructor.  My revised statement would be that In these rare specific circumstance where both a non-empty constructor must be used along with properties being instancied, then `New-Object` still must be used.

Comment: Can you share an example of something that can be done with `new-object` and cannot be done using the `::new` or hashtable casting syntax?